# Get average of 3 integers in decimal

Tags: c++

I have 3 integers:

```
int number1,number2,number3
```

I need the result of averaging them to be in decimal.

I have done:

```
float average = number1+number2+number3 / 3
```

And I get the wrong result.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Present the problem to us.  _"wrong result"_ is not it. We don't know what the correct result is. Also, show your code - the real code. No pictures.

Comment: Please reread your formula. `1+1+3/3` is 3. Does that make sense to you, as the average?

Answer (score 4):

A couple of things:

1. You have messed up the [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). What you have is essentially:

   ```
   number1 + number2 + (number3 / 3)
   ```

   This is because division has a higher precedence than addition. It's the same as what you learn about arithmetic at school. So you need parentheses around the addition to ensure it's evaluated first.
2. All these types are integers, so the result will be an integer. At least one of the values needs to be a `float` in order for the calculation to be done as float. I personally think it's cleaner to ensure everything is a float.

Taking the above into consideration, this is what you want:

```
float average = static_cast<float>(number1 + number2 + number3) / 3.0f;
```

Comment: Technically, since you are specifying the denominator as a `float`, you don't need to cast the numerator. The standard allows you to divide an `int` by a `float` and vice versa, the result will be a `float` either way.

Comment: Correct, but my preference is to be explicit, which can avoid silly bugs in future. I personally think code should clearly indicate when a type conversion is happening. But some will argue that explicit cast adds clutter.

Comment: Your approach calculates `number1 + number2 + number3` as an `int`.   Which, if the values are large enough, will cause undefined behaviour due to signed integer overflow.   To avoid that (with a trade-off of potential loss of precision instead of undefined behaviour) force conversion(s) to `float` BEFORE doing the addition, not after.